# Java - double definition in two interfaces

Tags: java

Class A can implement multiple interfaces.

What I do not understand is what happens in this case:

```
public interface example1 {
    void checkInt(int a);
}

public interface example2 {
    void checkInt(int b);
}

public class class1 implements example1,example2 {
    void checkInt(int c){
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    this.checkint(5);
}
```

I tried to run it, and it gives me compilation errors. But my question is in general, can I implement two interfaces, that have a functions with the same signature?

Comment: "Can I inherit fron two interfaces" - you don't inherit from interfaces, you implement them... What compilation errors did you get?

Comment: Yes, Implements. The errors don't matter. The situtaion is possible? Because It doesn't make sense - If I have 2 interfaces with the same name and signature but with a diffrent meaning?

Comment: I would find it confusing to have two methods with the same name but have incompatible meanings.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Why? for example "draw(card)": how to draw a card, and "draw(card)" how to draw a card to the screen. The same signature, but a diffrent meaning..

Comment: @Tom, Could you clearer as to what the different meaning is?  The first example could be drawing the screen as well.

Comment: @Tom: When the methods have different meanings (i.e. drawing the card from a stack of cards and drawing it on the screen), you will run into problems implementing them both to their specifications. But why should the compiler have to recognize this?

Comment: The code in the question would compile, apart from the `this.checkint(5);` line (since you can't put such a command outside of a method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What compilations errors are you getting?  Because `this.checkint` is in the wrong case, it should be `checkInt(5)` ?  Also you're reducing the scope of the method from implied public (as all interface methods are) to default (packaged protected).  The `checkInt` method needs to be public in the implementing class.

Both interfaces define the method, but this is fine as there is one implementation on `class1`.  So `class1` fulfils the implemented methods of each interface with its implementation of `checkInt(int i)`.  With interfaces you're only fulfilling a contract, so there is no ambiguity about which method to call - if you work with references of type `example1` or `example2` it will still be the same `checkInt` method on `class1` which gets invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The compilation error is because you are missing visibility attribute (public) in the implementing class for the method `checkInt` and you have a statement that's not enclosed by any method.

But in general if you have a class implementing multiple interfaces that have common method signatures,then the class will have just one implementation to satisfy both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your compilation error is from the `this.checkint(5)` line, and not the interface implementations. Implementing two interfaces that share a method with an identical signature is perfectly legal, and you have done so above.

You can think of it this way: when a class implements an interface, it agrees to implement all the methods defined by the interface. As long as you have fulfilled this requirement for each interface, it doesn't matter how many methods you've actually written to do so.

Also, consider how interfaces are actually used:

```
example1 e1 = new class1();
e1.checkInt(3); // Calls class1.checkInt()

example2 e2 = new class1();
e2.checkInt(3); // Also calls class.checkInt()
```

The interface variables are actually referring to an object of type class1, so it is class1's methods that matter, not what other interfaces class1 implements.

Answer (score 0):

You do not Inherit an interface, you implement it.  What implementing an interface does for you is to notify consumers of your class that you guarantee that you will have a certain set of methods available for use.  Many interfaces can have a single method signature in their contract but since only the implementing class has actual code, there is not and issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement both interfaces. However, this is usually not recommended, as it could lead to confusion as you say.

You can only implement both interfaces in the very specific case that the arguments, name and return types exactly match, otherwise there will be a conflict. If the names or argument types are different you will need to implement both separately. If all that differs is the return type, then it is impossible to implement both interfaces as they clash.

If the two interfaces happen to have a different meaning for the method, then you are better providing an adapter instead. See the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

[A whole article on solving this problem has been written here](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/ConflictingInterfacesPartI.pdf).

Your compilation errors are due to something else (in this case you haven't declared your implementing method `public`), and looking at the code sample you provided, probably lots of other things!

Comment: `You can only implement both interfaces in the very specific case that the arguments, name and return types exactly match, otherwise there will be a conflict`  Not entirely true . In that case you will need to implement each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Classes dont `inherit` from interfaces.

```
Classes inherit Classes
Interfaces inherit interfaces
Classes `implements` Interfaces
```

Your example is perfectly fine as Interface just declares signatures (or contract), does not define behaviour. Classes 'implement' Interfaces to provide behaviour. So a class implementing two interfaces can provide 'same' implementation to both methods - Contract is not voilated as the class `is` inplemeenting the behaviour.